# Website that was working stopped without any change

Tags: javascript, html

I thnik this could be a javascript, but not sure, because I didn`t change anything on the website, and sundelly it stopped working.

Here is the url - http://www.projetograndesmestres.com/

Here is the html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Grandes mestres</title>
    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/revolution-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Responsive -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,    maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk /html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/respond.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icons/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="images/icons/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="images/icons/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="images/icons/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/icons/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
     <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r; i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new   Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-91309624-1', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>


    </head>

    <body>





    <div class="page-wrapper">

    <!-- Preloader -->
    <div class="preloader"></div>

    <!-- Main Header -->
    <header class="main-header">
        <div class="auto-container clearfix">
            <!--Logo-->
            <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Meeton" title="Meeton"></a></div>

            <!--Main Menu-->
            <nav class="main-menu">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <!-- Toggle Button -->      
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse clearfix">                                                                                              
                    <ul class="navigation">
                        <li class="current dropdown"><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#programacao">Programação</a>                          
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ><a href="#myModal">COMPRAR PGM</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="contato.html">Contato</a>
                        </li>
                         <li class="dropdown"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pgmbr/"><span class="fa fa-facebook-f"></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/projetograndesmestres/"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></a>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <!--Main Menu End-->

        </div>
    </header>
    <!--End Main Header -->

    <!-- Main Slider -->
    <section class="main-slider">

        <div class="tp-banner-container">
            <div class="tp-banner">
                <ul>



                    <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1000" data-thumb="images/main-slider/image-6.jpg" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="Revelações">
                    <img src="images/main-slider/image-6.jpg" alt="" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat"> 

                    <div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="400" data-y="center" data-voffset="-220" data-speed="1500" data-start="500" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="slide-text"><p><h3>
                    Os atores Giovanna Lancelloti e <br />Felipe Roque já participaram. 

</h3></p></div></div>

                    <div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="315" data-y="center" data-voffset="-140" data-speed="1500" data-start="1000" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="slide-text"><p><h3>
                    Venha você também fazer parte dessa 
                    convenção!</h3></p></div></div>

                    <div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="315" data-y="center" data-voffset="-70" data-speed="1500" data-start="1000" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="slide-text"><p><h3>
                    O maior network para Atores e Modelos do Brasil. </h3></p></div></div>



                    <div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme voot2" data-x="left" data-hoffset="505" data-y="center" data-voffset="0" data-speed="1500" data-start="1500" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="links"><!--button type="button" class="theme-btn btn-style-one hvr-bounce-to-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="fa fa-play"></span>INSCRIÇÃO AQUI</button--><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#revelacoes" role="button">Revelações</a> </div></div>


                    <div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="315" data-y="center" data-voffset="100" data-speed="1500" data-start="1000" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="slide-text"><p><h3>
                    Teste de elenco para as séries "Geração Digital" e <br />"Relações" 
                    nos dias 20 e 21 de maio. </h3></p></div></div>

                    </li>





                    <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1000" data-thumb="images/main-slider/image-9.jpg" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="Jayme Monjardim">
                    <img src="images/main-slider/image-9.jpg" alt="" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat"> 

                    <div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="55" data-y="center" data-voffset="-200" data-speed="1500" data-start="500" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="big-title"><h2>Jayme Monjardim<br />Diretor Artístico</h2></div></div>

                    <!--div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="670" data-y="center" data-voffset="-170" data-speed="1500" data-start="1000" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="slide-text"><p><h3>Ganhador do Emmy Internacional pela obra <br /><strong>Verdades Secretas</strong> e autor da próxima <br />novela das 21h da Rede Globo</h3></p></div></div-->



                    <!--div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="115" data-y="center" data-voffset="15" data-speed="1500" data-start="1000" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="slide-text"><p><h3>
                    Os palestrantes walcyr carrasco e Mauro Mendonça  Filho <br />não tem nenhuma ligação com os 
                    testes das séries <br />nos dias 20 e 21 de maio </h3></p></div></div>

                    <div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="115" data-y="center" data-voffset="15" data-speed="1500" data-start="1000" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="slide-text"><p><h3>
                    Teste de elenco para as séries "Geração Digital" e <br />"Relações" 
                    nos dias 20 e 21 de maio. </h3></p></div></div-->


                    </li>

                    <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1000" data-thumb="images/main-slider/image-10.jpg" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="Duca Rachid">
                    <img src="images/main-slider/image-10.jpg" alt="" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat"> 



                    <!--div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="525" data-y="center" data-voffset="-120" data-speed="1500" data-start="1000" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="slide-text"><p><h3>Diretor de Núcleo ganhador de dois Emmys Internacional<br /> pelas obras <strong>Verdades Secretas e O Astro</strong>, diretor <br />da próxima novela das 21h da Rede Globo</h3></p></div></div-->



                    <!--div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="525" data-y="center" data-voffset="-05" data-speed="1500" data-start="1000" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="slide-text"><p><h3>
                    Os palestrantes walcyr carrasco e Mauro Mendonça  Filho <br />não tem nenhuma ligação com os 
                    testes das séries <br />nos dias 20 e 21 de maio </h3></p></div></div>

                    <div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="525" data-y="center" data-voffset="-05" data-speed="1500" data-start="1000" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="slide-text"><p><h3>
                    Teste de elenco para as séries "Geração Digital" e <br />"Relações" 
                    nos dias 20 e 21 de maio. </h3></p></div></div-->


                    </li>


                    <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1000" data-thumb="images/main-slider/image-4.jpg" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="Fátima Toledo">
                    <img src="images/main-slider/image-4.jpg" alt="" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat"> 

                    <div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="15" data-y="center" data-voffset="-220" data-speed="1500" data-start="500" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="big-title"><h2>Fátima Toledo<br />Preparadora de Elenco</h2></div></div>



                    <div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme voot2" data-x="left" data-hoffset="05" data-y="center" data-voffset="-110" data-speed="1500" data-start="1500" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="links"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="fatima.html" role="button">SAIBA MAIS</a></div></div-->

                    <!--div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="15" data-y="center" data-voffset="-20" data-speed="1500" data-start="1000" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="slide-text"><p><h3>
                    Teste de elenco para as séries "Geração Digital" e <br />"Relações" 
                    nos dias 20 e 21 de maio. </h3></p></div></div>

                    <div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="1160" data-y="center" data-voffset="180" data-speed="1500" data-start="1000" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="slide-text"><p><h6>
                    A confirmar</h6></p></div></div-->



                    </li>




                    <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1000" data-thumb="images/main-slider/image-1.jpg" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="Sergio Mattos">
                    <img src="images/main-slider/image-1.jpg" alt="" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat"> 

                    <div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="700" data-y="center" data-voffset="-200" data-speed="1500" data-start="500" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="big-title"><h2>Sergio Mattos <br /> Booker

</h2></div></div>

                    <!--div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="625" data-y="center" data-voffset="-80" data-speed="1500" data-start="1000" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="slide-text"><p><h4>A 
                    40 Graus Models deu um novo passo, abrindo seu departamento <br />de atores, hoje denominada DNArt com acompanhamento 
de<br /> carreira, assessoria de imprensa e estratégias 
de construção de<br /> imagem junto ao mercado, 
visando o lançamento de novos talentos <br /> no 
mundo da teledramaturgia, teatro e cinema.</h4></p></div></div-->

                    <div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme voot2" data-x="left" data-hoffset="690" data-y="center" data-voffset="-100" data-speed="1500" data-start="1500" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="links"><!--button type="button" class="theme-btn btn-style-one hvr-bounce-to-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="fa fa-play"></span>INSCRIÇÃO AQUI</button--><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="sergio.html" role="button">SAIBA MAIS</a> </div></div>


                    <div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="700" data-y="center" data-voffset="-20" data-speed="1500" data-start="1000" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="slide-text"><p><h3>
                    Teste de elenco para as séries "Geração<br /> Digital" e "Relações" 
                    nos dias 20 e 21 de maio. </h3></p></div></div>



                    </li>


                    <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1000" data-thumb="images/main-slider/image-5.jpg" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="Guilherme Abreu">
                    <img src="images/main-slider/image-5.jpg" alt="" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat"> 

                    <div class="tp-caption lfb tp-resizeme" data-x="left" data-hoffset="5" data-y="center" data-voffset="-220" data-speed="1500" data-start="500" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.01" data-endelementdelay="0.3" data-endspeed="1200" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="big-title"><h2>Guilherme Abreu<br /> Agente de atores</h2></div></div>


                </ul>

                <div class="tp-bannertimer"></div>`
            </div>
        </div>
    </section >




            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <!--Price Plans / Style Two-->
    <section id="inscricao" class="price-plans style-two">
        <div class="auto-container">

            <div class="sec-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="200ms" data-wow-duration="1000ms"><h2>Faça já sua inscrição</h2></div>
            <div class="sec-text wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="200ms" data-wow-duration="1000ms"><p>E garanta sua presença no Maior Networking de Atores e Modelos</p></div>


            <div class="row clearfix">

                <!--Table Column-->
                <article class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 table-column recommended wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0ms" data-wow-duration="1500ms">
                    <div class="table-inner hvr-sweep-to-right">
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <!--div class="half-column price">
                                <h4 class="amount"><sup>R$</sup>1.800**</h4>
                                <p>ATÉ 24 Fevereiro*</p>
                            </div-->
                            <div class="half-column list">
                                <h3>Condições:</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <br />
                                    <li>Parcele em até 10x sem juros no pagseguro</li>
                                    <br />
                                    <!--li>6x no cartão</li>
                                    <br />
                                    <li>2x no boleto</li>
                                    <br /-->


                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="links">
                        <!--a class="theme-btn btn-style-one hvr-bounce-to-right" href="https://projetograndesmestres.lojavirtualnuvem.com.br/produtos/convencao-projeto-grandes-mestres-edicao-rio-de-janeiro/" role="button"><span class="fa fa-play"></span>COMPRAR CONVENÇÃO PGM</a></div>
                        <!--button type="button" class="theme-btn btn-style-one hvr-bounce-to-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="fa fa-play"></span>INSCRIÇÃO AQUI</button-->
                        <button type="button" class="theme-btn btn-style-one hvr-bounce-to-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="fa fa-play"></span>COMPRAR CONVENÇÃO PGM</button>
                   </div>
                </article>

            </div>

        </div>
    </section>





                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </article>



            </div>




        </div>
    </section>



     <!--Intro Section-->
    <section class="intro-section" style="background-image:url(images/parallax/image-1.jpg);">
        <div class="auto-container">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 text-content">
                    <h2>O MAIOR NETWORK PARA ATORES E MODELOS</h2>
                    <div class="text">Traga seu Vídeo Book e Fotos, teremos agências realizando cadastro nos dias 20 e 21.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-right">
                <div class="links">
                <!--a class="theme-btn btn-style-one hvr-bounce-to-right" href="https://projetograndesmestres.lojavirtualnuvem.com.br/produtos/convencao-projeto-grandes-mestres-edicao-rio-de-janeiro/" role="button"><span class="fa fa-play"></span>COMPRAR CONVENÇÃO PGM</a></div-->
                    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                    <!--button type="button" class="theme-btn btn-style-one hvr-bounce-to-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="fa fa-play"></span>INSCRIÇÃO AQUI</button-->
                <button type="button" class="theme-btn btn-style-one hvr-bounce-to-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="fa fa-play"></span>COMPRAR CONVENÇÃO PGM</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

     <!--Sponsors-->
    <section class="sponsors">
        <div class="auto-container">
            <ul class="slider">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/clients/logo1.jpg" alt="" title=""></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/clients/logo2.jpg" alt="" title=""></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/clients/logo3.jpg" alt="" title=""></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/clients/logo5.jpg" alt="" title=""></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/clients/logo6.jpg" alt="" title=""></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/clients/logo7.jpg" alt="" title=""></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/clients/logo8.jpg" alt="" title=""></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!--Main Footer-->
    <footer class="main-footer">
        <!--Footer Upper-->


       <!--Footer Bottom-->
        <div class="footer-bottom">
            <div class="auto-container">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12 footer-logo"><img src="images/resource/ana.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>    
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12 footer-logo"><img src="images/resource/35mm2.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>

                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 footer-logo loot">&copy; 2017 PROJETO GRANDES MESTRES | Todos os direitos Reservados desenvolvido por<a href="http://www.neevasoft.com" target="_blank"> Neevasoft</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</div>
<!--End pagewrapper-->



<!--Scroll to top-->
<div class="scroll-to-top"></div>


<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
</script-->
<script src="js/revolution.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bxslider.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
       <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button><br />
          <h4 class="modal-title">Termos</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"> 
          <div class="row clearfix">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 contact-form wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="200ms" data-wow-duration="1500ms">

                        <!--Contact Form-->
                        <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="enviar_inscricao.php">
                          <div class="row clearfix">

                          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                         <div id="scroll" class="boot">
                          <strong>ACEITO E CONCORDO</strong> COM O TERMO   ABAIXO, REGIDO PELAS SEGUINTES CLÁUSULAS E CONDIÇÕES:





                          </div>
                          </div>
                          </div>





                            </div>


                        </form> 

                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="https://projetograndesmestres.lojavirtualnuvem.com.br/produtos/convencao-projeto-grandes-mestres-edicao-rio-de-janeiro/" role="button">Concordo</a>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
​

     </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Define "stopped working". I visited your link and the page seemed to load fine.

Comment: "suddenly stopped working" is not a sufficiently detailed problem description, please review [ask]

Comment: It's working again. Are you using a basic Domain Service (those one that includes cPanel or any administration panel)? This kind of things occurs because of the server or the HTTP server.

Comment: It seems related to one of the links (style, images, script, etc) you are including in the page. Some are broken, or take so much time to retrieve.

Comment: It came into a looping here for me

Comment: Off topic, but 96 requests just on the initial page load, before I even started scrolling? Just short of 20MB? seriously? And that figure going further up as soon as I start scrolling!? You should really send your page on a diet and try to get below 40/50 requests and 5MB of data on the initial request. Even that would still be heavy for a common web page, but the current state can only be desribed as morbidly obese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed an error 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).' The resource that can't be loaded is a file called 'preloader.gif.' It is referenced in this stylesheet: http://www.projetograndesmestres.com/css/style.css. See code below.

```
.preloader{ position:fixed; left:0px; top:0px; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:999999; background-color:#ffffff; background-position:center center; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image:url(../images/icons/preloader.GIF);
```

Try removing this line of code from the stylesheet and your page should load.

Comment: Thanks Emma, this was it. There was a looping cuz of the preloader

Comment: Happy to help you.